# mingw path in environment variable on windows10

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw-w64

I am trying to add a mingw compiler in windows on qtcreator and i have done what the internet has said, add the path to system environment variable. C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin is the path i used(no spaces) but when i tried to do a gcc -version in cmd, i get

```
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

setpath gives me

```
C:\>set path
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;...C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin;...
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

What do i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check it really exists there by running:

```
DIR C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin\gcc.exe
```

If it's not there then try

```
DIR C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin\*gcc.exe
```

to see if you have something like `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`, which is what you should use then instead.

Comment: Wow much thanks!! Stuck at this for so long. The x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc is the problem. I can rename it without any problem right?

Comment: Don't rename it, because then it will be missing. Build tools like CMake will actually look for this long name. But you could copy it and do the same for `g++.exe`.